# jquery UI button on checkbox

Tags: jquery-ui, checkbox

i have such a checkbox and i whant to turn it into jquery ui checkbox to look the same on all browsers.

```
<tr>
    <td valign="middle" class="ck"><input name="perk-senior" id="senior" type="checkbox" value="4" checked /></td>
    <td valign="middle"><div class="text">Show available plans for senior</div></td>
</tr>
```

[image]

but after i use

```
$('#senior').button()
```

the checkbox just disappears. I tried adding jqueryui icons, and removing css, it gives the same effect.

how can i make it into a standard checkbox with a tick icon on toogle?

Comment: $('#search') was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Should that not be:

```
$('.ck').button()
```

Or:

```
$('#senior').button()
```

You've selected the entire containing div and not the checkbox itself (presuming that the table is nested within a div named #search).